# Data Conflict 409 Error

Tags: couchdb

I am getting a Document Conflict 409 error when I try to add a document to CouchDB. The scenario is as follows.

1. Add Doc1 Rev1 to Couch using HTTP PUT
2. Delete Doc1 Rev1 from Couch using HTTP DELETE
3. Add Doc1 Rev2 to Couch using HTTP PUT

Why would step 3 cause Couch to return a Data Conflict 409 error? How can a document be in conflict with a deleted document? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Jim

Comment: Are you trying to add a revision to a document that does not exist? Step 1: rev1 created, Doc1 now exists. Step 2: rev1 deleted, Doc1 now doesn't exist. Step 3: add rev2 to Doc1, oops there's no Doc1!

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. To create a document, don't pass a _rev value in the body.